# Fail to Convert .mat to .csv file

Tags: matlab

I would like to convert matlab.mat file to a .csv file. Here is the loading procedure:

```
>> FileData = load('matlab.mat')

FileData = 

  struct with fields:

    MIMICtable: [278340×59 table]
```

Then I tried to save the CSV file but the following error occurs:

```
>> csvwrite('file.csv',MIMICtable)
Check for missing argument or incorrect argument data type in call to function 'real'.

Error in csvwrite (line 47)
    throw(e)
```

I am not sure the meaning of the error message. Could someone help?

Comment: Were there more lines to the error?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Nope

Comment: Shouldn't it be `csvwrite('file.csv',FileData.MIMICtable)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is a `table` object. Use the function [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) to write it to a CSV file. `csvwrite` accepts only numeric arrays as input.

Yes, this is a weird error message. On the other hand, `csvwrite` is no longer recommended, which means it has been superseded by a newer function, and is no longer maintained.